# php with curl sms sending with on live server

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, jquery-ui

```
function curl_request($url=false)
{

$ch=curl_init();
if($url)
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 60);  
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 60);  
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPGET, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true); 
$result = curl_exec($ch);
$httpcode = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);  
curl_close($ch);
return $result;
}

$data['update']=false;
$data['msg']='Record not found.';
switch($_POST['action'] ){
    case "validateAccountNumber" :
        $sql="SELECT user_id FROM tbl_user WHERE ".$_POST['fieldName']."='".$_POST['fieldValue']."'";
         $result = mysql_query ($sql);
         if(mysql_num_rows($result)){ 
             $_SESSION['account_no'] = $_POST['fieldValue'];        
             $data['update']=true;
             $data['msg']='Record found.';
         }  
    break;

    case "validateMobileNumber" :
    $sql="SELECT user_id FROM tbl_user WHERE ".$_POST['fieldName']."='".$_POST['fieldValue']."' AND account_no='".$_SESSION['account_no']."'";
         $result = mysql_query ($sql);
         if(mysql_num_rows($result)){
            $_SESSION['mobile_no'] = $_POST['fieldValue']; 
            // 
            $sms_code= makePin();
            $_SESSION['sms_code'] = $sms_code;    
            ///////////////////// Sengin Sms Code //////////////////////////
            $message = "Dear Member, your activation code is $sms_code. Thanks for registering, from www.chsonline.in.";

            $username = "xxxxxxxxxx";
            $password = "zzzzzzzzzz";
            $sendername = "chsonline";
            $url = "http://bulksms.mysmsmantra.com:8080/WebSMS/SMSAPI.jsp?username=".$username."&password=".$password."&sendername=".$sendername."&mobileno=91".$_SESSION['mobile_no']."&message=".urlencode($message);
             $data['sms_response'] = curl_request($url);
             $data['sms'] = $url;

            ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////  
            $data['update']=true;
            $data['msg']='A verification code have been sent in your mobile no.';
         }  
    break;
    default:
    break;
}
echo json_encode($data);
die(); 
}
```

**ths is an php code:** When i was send the sms with this code, its send sms on **localhost**, but on live server its not send sms only This notification gives

- A verification code have been sent in your mobile no.

Code execute Proper, but no sms sending.
My Hosting or Domain with **Godaddy.in**

Answer (score 0):

contact you hosting company for the curl enable or not on your selected hosting plan. it seems like on your server `CURL` is disabled.

You can check your php.ini configration for check same.

TO check php info :

1. create on file phpinfo.php on server
2. Put `<?php echo phpinfo();?>`
3. Run you phpinfo.php file on server
4. Find **curl** and check is it enable or disable?

Comment: only this code not working, Other Curl php sms program working Fine.

Comment: I created a sms sending program to enter manually Msg or receiver number its send sucess fully

Comment: Please see.... my php info, i ad given link, would you suggest me.. its what is the problems,

Comment: its might be issue of case sensivity on server because your server is linux based and you localhost is windows so in locahost you have not such issue, but on server case sensivity checked so you might have got this issue.

Comment: also try to print $result in curl_request function call

Comment: what case Sensivity, i dont have much experience abot this.... please will you suggest me, how to solve please please, i am in trouble.

Comment: what is return from `curl_request()` ? what is the value of `$result` when it return from function